# which design pattern i should follow to develope asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net

There are lots of design patterns are available for developing the asp.net site. Every one design patterns are having their pros and cons. I want to develop high performance application using asp.net. Which pattern i should follow?

Comment: What patterns are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice that I've seen today separates all of the business logic from the presentation layer.  Classic ASP.NET Webforms tend to make this a bit more difficult and encourage lazy programming because you can use all of the events off of the page rather than forcing good code separation and single responsibility principle.

If you were to utilize the ASP.NET MVC framework, you will most likely have a structure in place that would lend towards better coding practices.  However, you can still find ways to fall back to the webforms style of coding.

If you focus on the **[single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)** and **[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.asp.net%2Fmvc%2F&ei=2HsMSrrdLJq6tAOhm-XpAg&usg=AFQjCNG1FWlq5gZ1lBZOIcCgJoB9yLn9pA&sig2=FQd0g1vrJbPQeCjuryuqbA)**, you're going to be off to a great start.  **[Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)** may also be worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 1):

It can depend on the applications aims and goals. Is it going to be user-centric? Pretty/Ajaxy? SOAP Service?

Design patters are there to make life simpler. If you get it wrong, then it may well make life harder. Architectural patterns, behavioural patters, Structural Patterns and Data Semantics can only be decided in the context of the application's **functionality**, which form, in the end, is a slave to.

Answer (score 0):

[Model–view–controller (MVC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) is a popular one used to develop this sort of things

Answer (score 0):

There's a really good, free [architecture guide book](http://www.codeplex.com/AppArchGuide) available from patterns & practices.  It discusses in some detail many of the different patterns and where they can be used in the development of an ASP.NET (and many other types of) application.